# Handles an Event from Control in another class

Tags: vb.net, class, events, event-handling

I want to fire an event in another class.
And my problem is I don't know how to make it.

I'm trying to use `Inherits` statement to my Form and add my class name to it, and it works as I hope:

```
Public Class Frm_Main_Copy

    Inherits ToolStripMenuApp 
     'I have a ToolStripMenu that has declared before on my class and it sounds like this:
     'Public Shared WithEvents Cat000x86_64App As ToolStripMenuItem
    ...
    Private Sub IsClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Cat000x86_64App.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

but the designer form messed up(returns a fatal error) and I should delete the `Inherits` statement, and the others.

Tried to act as form designer script(Trying to put this code to my class):

```
Friend WithEvents BlahBlah As RadioButton 'For example
```

It didn't worked,

Declaring a variable for my class and It didn't worked too

Searched on the Internet and it seems likely more complicated than I thought...

Anyone can help? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form is not a form unless it inherits, either directly or indirectly, the `Form` class.  You cannot inherit any type that is not itself a form and expect your type to be a form.  With that code, if `ToolStripMenuApp` is not a form then `Frm_Main_Copy` is not a form either, hence no form designer.

If what you're actually saying is that you have an instance of that `ToolStripMenuApp` that contains a `TooStripMenuItem` whose `Click` event you want to handle in `Frm_Main_Copy` then the first step is to not declare `Cat000x86_64App` as `Shared`.  `Frm_Main_Copy` needs to declare a method capable of handling that event:

```
Private Sub IsClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '...
End Sub
```

Note that there is no `Handles` clause because there's no `WithEvents` variable in that class whose event you are handling.

Next, `Frm_Main_Copy` must have access to the appropriate instance of `ToolStripMenuApp`.  It's impossible for us to say how best to do that based on the information provided but it might be as simple as this:

```
Dim tsma As New ToolStripMenuApp
```

You then register your method as a handler for the appropriate event:

```
AddHandler tsma.Cat000x86_64App.Click, AddressOf IsClicked
```

If you use `AddHandler`, make sure to use `RemoveHandler` when you're done with either object.  I suggest that you do some reading based on this information.

Comment: Actually `Frm_Main_Copy` is a Form that has a designer form. Your answer is helpful...